# I need to update all values keeping properties same in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I need to update all property values keeping property names same in `Neo4j`, but property values are not getting updated. 
**For example**, I have column names as Family, Question, Level, Multiple_Inputs, Comments & Documents. I want all column values to be updated but column names remain same. Can someone suggest?

The code I'm using is

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///file_name.csv') yield map as map
MATCH (qa:QA {Family:map.Family}) SET qa.Question=map.Question,qa.Level=map.Level,qa.Multiple_Inputs=map.Multiple_Inputs,qa.Comments=map.Comments,qa.Documents=map.Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a shorter version of the code you are currently using:

```
CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///file_name.csv') yield map as map
MATCH (qa:QA {Family:map.Family}) 
SET qa += apoc.map.clean(map,['Family'],[])
```

Comment: No, update values but keep keys same.

Comment: Well yes, exactly

Comment: This code above which I wrote isn't working. I need to know my mistake.